# Change instance attributes from method added on the fly

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am try to change the instance attributes from the method added in run time and continue to use the same in next in flow methods.

```
    class Test

      def start
        @s = 5
        puts "start #{@s}"
      end

      def test_1
        @s = 4
        puts "test_1 #{@s}"
      end

      def flow
        start
        test_2
        puts "flow #{@s}"
      end
    end

Test.class_eval("def test_2\n  puts 'test_2 1 #{@s}'\n   @s = 7\n test_1\n puts 'test_2 2 #{@s}'\n end\n")
  t = Test.new
  t.flow
```

The results of that is :
start 5
test_2 1 
test_1 4
**test_2 2** 
flow 4

So i coudl not figure out what is the reason of skipping the print of test_2 1 printing and why the value of the class attribute is not updated from the new evaluated method.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your example line for `class_eval` enclosed in double quotes, therefore Ruby prepare a substitution for `@s` variable (at this stage this variable equals `nil`). Change your code so:

```
Test.class_eval('def test_2; puts "test_2 1 #{@s}";   @s = 7; test_1; puts "test_2 2 #{@s}"; end')
# =>
    start 5
    test_2 1 5
    test_1 4
    test_2 2 4
    flow 4
```

or use block together with `class_eval` (that's much better, I believe)

```
Test.class_eval do
  def test_2
    puts "test_2 1 #{@s}"
    test_1
    puts "test_2 2 #{@s}"
  end
end
```

And one more note. Your `@s = 7` assignment is redundant because in `test_1` method you immediately prepare yet another assignment `@s = 4`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.This is only simplified example of DSL which is based on methods defined from UI and stored in DB. My problem is that newly defined methods which are evaluated and get the class attributes do not updated these attributed after exit from the method. Let's say I have an Array of strings defined as a class attribute. In a evaluated method I change one of the strings from Array and after exit I do not see this String changed in next method from this class. Assuming that this is kinda typo error or may be I missing some ryby principles